# How to get Facebook user profile(swift)

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I have worked on getting user profile info by swift.
There are no bugs but I would like to check whether this code is working or not because of the bug below, I could not check in the simulator.

Bug: Falling back to storing access token in NSUserDefaults because of simulator bug

As I know, this bug will not be happen at the real device.

```
class FetchUserProfileController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var userFullName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var userProfileImage: UIImageView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    userFullName.text = ""

    if let _ = FBSDKAccessToken.current()
    {
        fetchUserProfile()
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}


func fetchUserProfile()
{
    let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"id, email, name, picture.width(200).height(200)"])

    graphRequest.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if ((error) != nil)
        {
            print("Error took place: \(error)")
        }
        else
        {
            print("Print entire fetched result: \(result)")

            let fbData:[String:AnyObject] = result as! [String : AnyObject]

            let userName : NSString? = fbData["name"]! as? NSString
            let facebookID : NSString? = fbData["id"]! as? NSString

            if let imageURL = ((fbData["picture"] as? [String: Any])?["data"] as? [String: Any])?["url"] as? String {
                //Download image from imageURL
            }

        }
    })
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work on a normal device. Facebook Login SDK prevents the iOS simulator from caching the access token. In case you don't have a real device and have to check the login on a simulator, do the following:

1) Search for `FBSDKKeychainStore.m:` in your project.

2) Go to line 94 and add `key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_fix", key];` just before `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:value forKey:key];`

3) Go to line 135 and add the same, `key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_fix", key];` just before `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:value forKey:key];`

It will still print the bug line that you mentioned but you'll be able to facebook login using a simulator